# Wiki app for asp.net and/or IIS 7.0

Tags: wiki, asp.net

I've been searching for a wiki that can be installed in our server, but I haven't found anything active. We have IIS7 and Windows Server 2008 and it should run in a sql-server database.

I found a few that were PHP-based, but I assume that they won't run on IIS. We cannot install another web server.

We just need a platform like wiki for documenting. It doesn't matter what development language was used, but it should run in IIS 7.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to list the features the wiki must/should have.

Comment: DB or File-based? Version controlled? Any particular markup capabilities? Etc, etc...

Comment: Why not just install [PHP on IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh994590(v=ws.11))? No need for a second webserver or anything else. Then you can use your existing server to run those you found.